# How to correctly control the rotation of the wheels on the car - three.js & cannon-es

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, cannon.js

## I cannot combine the horizontal movement of the wheels with the vertical movement.

Additionally, the wheels only move forward. I have no idea how to check if the vehicle is moving forward or backward in order to be able to properly handle the movement of the wheels.

**Watch the video:**
https://youtu.be/NDMsXG6lmc8

## How it looks from the code side:

**Turning the wheels horizontally:**

- The function is run after pressing the "a" or "d" key
- The deg variable takes values {0, Math.PI / 8}

```
const steeringWheels = (deg) => {
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontOponaLeft.rotation.z = deg;
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontFelgaLeft.rotation.z = deg;
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontFelgaRight.rotation.z = deg;
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontOponaRight.rotation.z = deg;
}
```

**Rotating the wheels vertically**

- Function called when each frame is rendered

```
const moveVehicle = (delta) => {
    options.vehilce.model.position.copy(options.vehilce.cannon.chassisBody.position.clone().vadd(new CANNON.Vec3(0, -.2, 0)));
    options.vehilce.model.quaternion.copy(options.vehilce.cannon.chassisBody.quaternion);

    angularVelocity = options.vehilce.cannon.wheelBodies[0].angularVelocity.length();

    options.vehilce.wheelFrontFelgaLeft.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontFelgaRight.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontOponaLeft.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelFrontOponaRight.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelBackFelgaLeft.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelBackFelgaRight.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelBackOponaLeft.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
    options.vehilce.wheelBackOponaRight.rotateX(angularVelocity * delta);
}
```

**You can check out the full code here:**
https://github.com/kwiatu-dev/sphere-collision/tree/feature

**To run the project, type:**

1. npm install
2. parcel

**I would like to be able to properly control the movement of the wheels while the vehicle is moving.**
If you are able to help me, please help.

*Feel free to review the code and give me any tips. I'm just starting to learn.*